While waiting for opportunity card in Germany, can I stay or do I have to leave?
My Norwegian visa will expire at the end of August due to the bankruptcy of the company I used to work for. Even after trying a lot, I couldn't manage a new job in Norway. So I applied for an opportunity card from the German Embassy in Oslo. My spouse lives in Germany and I am living with her now. Can I stay in Germany while my visa is being processed or must I return to my home country after August? If I have to return to my home country, can I still process the visa from Norway?
